# Creating a string of combined values from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I built a SQL query which returns the following results:

```
ID   Number ID  IndexColumn String_To_Use   Checking_ID
0000    1   0000    1                         -2
1000    2   1000    2                         -2
1020    3   1020    3                         -2
1130    4   1130    4                         -2
1198    5   NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1199    6   1199    5                         -2
1210    7   1210    6                         -2
1240    8   NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1250    9   NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1260    10  1260    7                         7
1261    11  NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1280    12  NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1296    13  NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1298    14  NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
1299    15  1299    8                         8
1501    16  NULL    9999     NULL             NULL
```

I need to populate the column "String_To_Use" with "ID" values in such a way that If "Checking_ID" column has values -2 more than once repeating (it means user chose IDs in a range), these repeating values would be displayed as "0000-1130"; if values -2 is not being repeated, then for example "1260". 
Based on this logic, the above table will contain the following values in the String_To_Use column:

```
ID   Number ID  IndexColumn String_To_Use   Checking_ID
0000    1   0000    1       0000-1130         -2
1000    2   1000    2       0000-1130         -2                 
1020    3   1020    3       0000-1130         -2
1130    4   1130    4       0000-1130         -2
1198    5   NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1199    6   1199    5       0000-1210         -2
1210    7   1210    6       0000-1210         -2                  
1240    8   NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1250    9   NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1260    10  1260    7       1260              7
1261    11  NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1280    12  NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1296    13  NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1298    14  NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
1299    15  1299    8       1299              8
1501    16  NULL    9999    NULL              NULL
```

thank you!!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Please @user10581977, I would suggest editing the question by replacing the external images as tables (maybe with help of: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) so this question is useful in the future, even if the images are down, and also to help readability.

Comment: Also, if @gordon-linoff answer it's on point (as it seems for your 'thank you' note), please mark the answer as the one solving your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define groups of "adjacency".  In this case, you can simply do a cumulative sum of the number of times that `checking_id` is not `-2`.

After that, the rest is window functions and string manipulation:

```
select t.*,
       (case when checking_id <> -2
             then min(id) over (partition by grp) + '-' + max(id) over (partition by grp)
             else id
        end) as string_to_use
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when checking_id <> -2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

This version assumes that `id` is a string.  If it is a number, the code is easily adapted by cluttering it with `cast()` or `convert()`.

Comment: the "max(id) over (partition by grp)" is giving error, "An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: the only way so far to make it partially work, it is like below:

Comment: This answer is a very smart and useful answer but its not entirely correct, here are some comments:1) "over (order by id) as grp" ==> it gives error; 2) "checking_id <> -2" ==> it gives incorrect results, here for the logic to work, it needs to be "checking_id = -2". I have edited the answer below with the output. But even making these changes the query needs some additional input to work properly. Could please someone help on fixing it. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*,
     (case when Checking_id = -2
             then min(id) over (partition by grp) + '-' + max(id) over (partition by grp)
             else id
      end) as string_to_use
from (select t.*
            ,sum(case when Checking_id = -2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t order by id;

ID  Number  ID  IndexColumn String_To_Use   Checking_id    grp   string_to_use
0000    1   0000    1                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1000    2   1000    2                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1020    3   1020    3                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1130    4   1130    4                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1198    5   NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1199    6   1199    5                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1210    7   1210    6                             -2        1    0000 -1210 
1240    8   NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1250    9   NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1260    10  1260    7                             7         0    1260 
1261    11  NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1280    12  NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1296    13  NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1298    14  NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
1299    15  1299    8                             8         0    1299 
1501    16  NULL    9999    NULL                NULL        0    NULL
```

Comment: String_To_Use column output still not giving the correct output when in ranges; correct should be:                                                                                                     1) First 4 rows ==> "0000-1130" ; 2) Six and seventh rows ==> "1199-1210"